# Structure variable in an if statement

Tags: c, structure

I need to make an C application for school and im stuck at one bit. I filled my struct with word from a file wich works fine, except for the time it just prints a random integer i guess?

My code:

```
char buffer[20];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   fgets(buffer,20,fp);
   apcWordList[i].pcWord = strdup(buffer);
   apcWordList[i].cMaxScore = 0;
   apcWordList[i].tTime = time(NULL);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Now what i wanted to do was this(sSecretWord is the word the person guessed and score the points he got for guessing the word):

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  fgets(buffer,20,fp);
  if(apcWordList[i].pcWord == sSecretWord && score > apcWordList[i].cMaxScore) {
      apcWordList[i].cMaxScore = score;
      apcWordList[i].tTime = time(NULL);
  }
}
```

but it crashes and I am really confused how to compare the variables and change them when needed. I hope I have explained it well enough and my English could be read well.

Comment: Typo: `for(i - 0; < 10; i++)` should be `for(i = 0;i < 10; i++)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `pcWord` is a `char *`, you cannot compare that pointer using `==`, most of the time.

There is no string data type in C, a string is never a single value.

You must use `strcmp()`:

```
if(strcmp(apcWordList[i].pcWord, sSecretWorD) == 0 &&
   score > apcWordList[i].cMaxScore)
```

The rest of your code makes little sense, I'm afraid. The loop has a typo, and there's no connection between the `fgets()` and the `if`. I don't think the `fgets()` should be in the second part of the code, at all.

Comment: Okay i tried strcmp() function and it worked. This should help me in the right direction thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following expression in your `if` condition

```
apcWordList[i].pcWord == sSecretWord
```

compares the memory addresses they evaluate to and not the values stored at those memory locations which is probably what you want. You should use `strcmp` instead to compare the strings pointed to by above two variables.

```
strcmp(apcWordList[i].pcWord, sSecretWorD) == 0
```